# Using c macro for variables

Tags: c, macros

I want to access several variables of the form:

```
int arr1=1;
int arr2=1;
int arr3=1;
```

So I wrote

```
#define arr(i) arr##i
```

but following code piece doesnt work as i expect

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
int arr1=1;
int arr2=1;
int arr3=1;
int j;
    for(j=1; j<3; j++)
        printf("%d",arr(j));

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are arrays not suitable for what you want to do?

Comment: For the future (for a different project) you might like to read about [Hash Tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The macro code is used for pre-processor phase and not for the runtime phase

if you generate your preprocessor code with `gcc -E`. You will see that your code is equivalent to:

```
int main(){
int arr1=1;
int arr2=1;
int arr3=1;
int j;
    for(j=1; j<3; j++)
        printf("%d",arrj);

return 0;
}
```

When you build your program, the gcc generate anoter c code from your c code and in which it replace all macros in your code by the macro contents( This phase is called preprocesser phase). and then generate asm code and then generate the binary file.

You can see the generated c code (from your code) by the `gcc -E`: code of preprocessor phase

Answer (score 6):

You cannot do this. Variable names don't exist at runtime in C.

Your macro will expand to `arrj`, which is an undefined variable name. Use a proper array:

```
int arr[] = { 1, 1, 1 };
```

then print `arr[j]`, but loop like this:

```
for(j = 0; j < sizeof arr / sizeof *arr; ++j)
  printf("%d\n, arr[j]);
```

Answer (score 0):

So that's going to produce `arrj` as a result.

The macro phase of C is something that happens before the program is run, even before it is parsed as actual C.

Long ago, the preprocessor was a totally separate program that knew very little about the C language.

Like most compilers today, `cc` back then just ran the different phases. Before it ran the compiler, assembler, and linker, it ran `cpp`, the *C preprocessor*.

And *cpp* just parsed the definitions, then it expanded the macros, and then it quit. Then *cc* would run the compiler. These days, the macro expansion is built in to the compiler proper but it processes the textual input of the program according to the original design.

There is still a `/usr/bin/cpp` on some systems today, but it's usually just a shell script that runs the compiler image with options that say *don't compile*.